# Compiling iOS projects for Windows Phone with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I attended a Microsoft presentation recently where the speaker said that it would be possible to compile an iOS project for Windows Phone with the upcoming Visual Studio 2015. Great!

So I got the new Visual Studio 2015 RC and installed everything - not to miss anything.

On a Mac an XCode project is a .xcodeproj file but it is actually a folder structure - and that's how Windows sees it. Inside this folder structure there's a file called project.pbxproj but it is not recognized by Visual Studio when I try to open an existing project.

So the question is, how do I open an XCode project in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not included by default as it is not yet finished,

https://dev.windows.com/en-US/uwp-bridges/project-islandwood

Answer (score 0):

To open an Xcode project in Visual Studio is required to use the tool vsimporter.

This tool is present in open source bridge Project from Microsoft GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC).

***Check the Readme file before to start

Using vsimporter

The vsimporter tool enables you to import your Xcode project into a new Visual Studio Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app project with Objective-C support.

To use the tool:

1. Download the prebuilt SDK from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/releases/download/0.1-preview/winobjc.zip) and extract the files to a directory (for example  `c:\winobjc`)
2. From a command prompt, navigate to the directory containing your Xcode project, for example  `c:\winobjc\samples\WOCCatalog`
3. At the command prompt, run vsimporter.exe
   `c:\winobjc\samples\WOCCatalog> ..\..\bin\vsimporter.exe`
4. A Visual Studio solution file is created in your current directory, double click this file to open your project in Visual Studio
5. Press Ctrl-F5 to build your app and run it on your PC.

You can also pass the -i option at the command line to run the vsimporter tool in interactive mode. Interactive mode lets you see and select the specific configurations of the Xcode project that you wish to import. By default vsimporter creates a Visual Studio solution that targets Windows 10. If you'd like to target Windows 8.1 (Phone or Store), use the -format option and specify one of winstore8.1, winphone8.1, or winstore10 (winstore10 is the default).

For help running vsimporter, use the -help option at the command line to see the full set of supported options.

To see the complete tutorial, please visit this [link](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/18/portando-apps-ios-para-windows/)